# NSLog not working when I make a method call in objective c

Tags: ios, xcode, nslog

I'm working on my first ground-up iOS app. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't seem to ferret out the problem.

I have an app with some IBActions in it, which do two things:

1) Outputs some simple text via NSLog (to let me know the action worked) - **this works okay (it outputs my text via NSLog)**

2) Makes a call to a method in a custom class which should also output an NSLog statement. - **this doesn't work (no text output via NSLog)**

I'm also struggling a bit with where to create the instances of my classes so that they are accessible elsewhere in my code.

Here's the code:

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  OrcAndPie
//
//  Created by me on 4/27/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 me. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Player.h"
#import "Orc.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    // Variables that you want to access globally go here?
    Player *wizard;
    Orc *grunty;

}

-(IBAction)takePie:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)castFireball:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)attack:(id)sender;



@end
```

and

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  OrcAndPie
//
//  Created by me on 4/27/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 me. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Player.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)takePie:(id)sender{
    // Player attempts to take the pie
    // If Orc's health is > 0, don't let the player take the pie
    // If the Orc's health is <= zero, let the player take the pie
    NSLog(@"IBAction - player attempted to take the pie.");
    [wizard takePie];

}

-(IBAction)castFireball:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"IBAction - player cast fireball.");
    [wizard castFireball];
}
-(IBAction)attack:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"IBAction - player attacked.");
    [wizard attackOrc];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    Player *wizard = [[Player alloc]init];
    Orc *grunty = [[Orc alloc]init];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

and

```
//
//  Player.h
//  OrcAndPie
//
//  Created by me on 4/27/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 me. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Player : NSObject

@property int maxHealth;
@property int currentHealth;
@property int armorClass;
@property int meleeToHitModifier;


-(void)setHeathBar;
-(void)attackOrc;
-(void)castFireball;
-(void)takePie;


@end
```

and

```
//
//  Player.m
//  OrcAndPie
//
//  Created by me on 4/27/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 me. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Player.h"

@implementation Player

@synthesize maxHealth;
@synthesize currentHealth;
@synthesize armorClass;
@synthesize meleeToHitModifier;

-(void)setHealthBar {
    NSLog(@"Player health is 15");
    return;

}

-(void)attackOrc {
    // roll a d20
    // add the "to hit" modifier
    // compare the result to the orc's armor class
    NSLog(@"Player - Player attached the Orc");
    return;

}
-(void)castFireball{
    NSLog(@"Player - Player casts Fireball");
    return;

}
-(void)takePie{
    NSLog(@"Player - Player attempts to take pie");
    return;

}

@end
```

Note: I also have an Orc class defined, but it looks fairly identical to the player class shown.

Thanks in advance for the help!

-- Eddie

Comment: Have you installed breakpoints in your code to be sure you're getting to where you think you're getting to?

Comment: (Note that there's no code above to initialize wizard instance variable, and making a call with a nil object pointer is a no-op in Objective-C.)

Comment: I put some breakpoints in the class, but they didn't appear to be reached.

Comment: You're not initializing `wizard` (even though you think you are).

Comment: I want to initialize wizard in a place that makes sense so that all of the IBActions can call the proper methods. Where should I be initializing wizard?

Comment: Wherever, but you gotta initialize it.  (Vs initializing a local variable by the same name.)

Comment: I assume you're referring to this:
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    // Variables that you want to access globally go here?
    Player *wizard;
    Orc *grunty;

}

I can see how that's not correct, but b/c I'm a complete newb, I need a little push in the right direction. Any suggestions as to where to place my alloc/init code?

Comment: To elaborate on Hot Licks' comment: initialize a Player object called 'wizard' like so: `wizard = [[Player alloc]init];`

Comment: I tried the alloc/init thing in the same location as the Player *wizard; Orc *grunty;, but xcode doesn't like it when I do that.

Comment: Sorry, having an edit nightmare. Above code should work for initializing a Player object. This should work for any Objective-C object that inherits from NSObject (ie, all of them).

Comment: @davidf2281 when I do this 
`@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    // Variables that you want to access globally go here?
    Player *wizard = [[Player alloc]init];
}
` 
I get errors `Expected ';' at end of declaration list`

Comment: viewDidLoad is initializing LOCAL variables with the same names as your globals -- it's not initializing the globals.  Drop the type (and `*`) from the assignment statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ViewController.h (which you should call by some more distinctive name, FYI) should look like this:

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  OrcAndPie
//
//  Created by me on 4/27/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 me. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Player.h"
#import "Orc.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property Player *wizard;
@property Orc *grunty;

-(IBAction)takePie:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)castFireball:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)attack:(id)sender;

@end
```

Then in your ViewController.m, your viewDidLoadMethod should look like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.wizard = [[Player alloc]init];
    self.grunty = [[Orc alloc]init];

}
```

This should at least ensure you have an instantiated instance of Player that you can call methods on, so your `NSLog` should be reached.

Comment: Finally scrolled down the page to see your answer. Thanks, give me a few minutes to try it out.

Comment: I should add that whenever you now refer to your wizard in your ViewController.m, you should refer to it as self.wizard, eg `[self.wizard castFireball]`.

Comment: So, that went pretty well, but now my IBActions which have the `[wizard takePie];` etc throws an error: `Use of undeclared identifier 'wizard'; did you mean '_wizard'? - hah, just saw your above comment, nvm.

Comment: Heh. Glad to help. iOS development can seem completely random when you're new to it.

Comment: Using properties should not be necessary.  The OP's original scheme of using instance vars should have worked, had he only initialized the right vars.

Comment: Not necessary, but good OOP practice. And this place is all about learning and best practice, right?